# Apache - how to make http requests into https only?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, zend-framework2, centos, httpd.conf

How to tell if http://ttt.com or http://www.ttt.com is used by the user, redirect it to https://www.ttt.com ?

httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName www.ttt.com
 ServerAlias ttt.com
 DocumentRoot /home/www/html/ttt/public
 <Directory /home/www/html/ttt/public>
    #Options ExecCGI
    #AddDefaultCharset utf-8
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(files)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Not duplicate. Zend Framework 2 is used already, the one you reference is not working (already tried)

Comment: @YumYumYum: Can you clarify what is not working with suggested answers by starkeen?

Comment: https://paste.fedoraproject.org/362573/23763341/ - i am getting this ERROR when i use Zend Framework 2 with .htaccess

Comment: @starkeen: please NOTE its not same question. i am in different environment using Zend Framework which already have its own .htaccess requirement. See the configuration which is working from "here link"

Comment: @YumYumYum the accepted answer is same as the other answers on the duplicate question. Do you still think this isnt..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following Code at the main directory .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Comment: Not working. when i type `http://www.example.com` its going to `https://www.example.com` when i type `http://example.com` its going to `https://example.com` instead of `https://www.example.com`, when i type `http://www.example.com/contactus` its failing to find a page by moving to `https://www.example.com/contactus` even the page is there.

Comment: it work for me fine , restart your server and empty cache & cookies from browser and try it again

Comment: I just did 50 times restart Apache, Can you check why its not working? `http://example.org` not getting into `https://www.example.org`

Comment: Just replace the line RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R] with RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/16220428/ - please see this is still not working when i try with Google chrome, Opera latest version for example: `http://example.org` is not going to `https://www.example.org` but the rest is working.

Comment: remove the history cookies & cache from chrome browser

Comment: Remove cache, cookies, uninstalled opera, firefox, chromium, google chrome. But still same.

Comment: Problem is solved. Its very complicated but solved. Basically its happening cause i use Zend Framework 2, where i need already another .htaccess to handle the php files. and then additionally i need to do redirection of http:// or http://www

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL

> ## Redirect Request to SSL
>
> Let's say you want http://www.example.com/secure/ to always be sent
>   over SSL (I presume here that both the normal and the SSL vhost have
>   the same content). You could do this by linking to the correct page
>   from within your HTML pages... but there will always be some user who
>   will sneak by it that way.
>
> ### Using virtual hosts (using redirect)
>
> When using SSL, you will frequently have at least two virtual hosts:
>   one on port 80 to serve ordinary requests, and one on port 443 to
>   serve SSL. If you wish to redirect users from the non-secure site to
>   the SSL site, you can use an ordinary [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive inside the
>   non-secure VirtualHost:
>
> ```
> NameVirtualHost *:80
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>    ServerName mysite.example.com
>    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
>    Redirect permanent /secure https://mysite.example.com/secure
> </VirtualHost>
>
> <VirtualHost _default_:443>
>    ServerName mysite.example.com
>    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
>    SSLEngine On
> # etc...
> </VirtualHost>
> ```
>
> When redirecting everything you don't even need a DocumentRoot:
>
> ```
> NameVirtualHost *:80
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>    ServerName www.example.com
>    Redirect permanent / https://secure.example.com/
> </VirtualHost>
>
> <VirtualHost _default_:443>
>    ServerName secure.example.com
>    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
>    SSLEngine On
> # etc...
> </VirtualHost>
> ```
>
> **Note**: redirect can also be used inside .htaccess files or to address
>   particular URLs, as in:
>
> Example:
>
> > Redirect permanent /login https://mysite.example.com/login
>
> ### Using mod_rewrite
>
> While the  solution is recommended because it is simpler
>   and safer, you can also use mod_rewrite to get the same effect as
>   described here: [RewriteHTTPToHTTPS](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS)

From https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect:

> ```
> # Redirect to a URL on a different host Redirect "/service" "http://foo2.example.com/service"
>
> # Redirect to a URL on the same host Redirect "/one" "/two"
> ```
>
> If the client requests http://example.com/service/foo.txt, it will be
>   told to access http://foo2.example.com/service/foo.txt instead. This
>   includes requests with GET parameters, such as
>   http://example.com/service/foo.pl?q=23&a=42, it will be redirected to
>   http://foo2.example.com/service/foo.pl?q=23&a=42. Note that POSTs will
>   be discarded. Only complete path segments are matched, so the above
>   example would not match a request for
>   http://example.com/servicefoo.txt. For more complex matching using the
>   expression syntax, omit the URL-path argument as described below.
>   Alternatively, for matching using regular expressions, see the
>   [RedirectMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) directive.

If you want both the `www.example.com/*` and the `example.com/*` to be redirected you could make two VirtualHost with different ServerName or you can use the Rewrite plugin.

Comment: I need to put any url http://theGiallo.com or http://www.theGiallo.com or http://theGiallo.com/contact into https://www.theGiall.com/..

Comment: `Redirect permanent / https://example.org/` does this line convert all the pages? such as if the page is `/page1` will it move to `https://example.org/page1`?

Comment: What? I don't understand.

Comment: Updating the answer.

Comment: ITS NOT WORKING. only the page www.example.org when i visit going to https://www.example.org but when i type www.example.org/test it does not find the page and throwing error page not found

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from the httpd.conf with the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.ttt.com
    Redirect "/" "https://www.ttt.com/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.ttt.com
    ...
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Or from the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: Not working, please see the comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37032433/285594