# Redirect all version of URLs to https using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect all version of my website URL to `https://www`. by using .htaccess file but getting problem with it.

- `ranglerz.com`
- `www.ranglerz.com`
- `http://ranglerz.com`
- `http://www.ranglerz.com`
- `https://www.ranglerz.com`
- `https://ranglerz.com`

all above versions of URLs are working but last URL is not redirecting with www, here is the code what I'm using in .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} !^www.ranglerz.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.ranglerz.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: **(Possibly) Related:** https://serverfault.com/questions/570288/is-it-bad-to-redirect-http-to-https

Comment: Check this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050590/redirect-non-www-to-www-in-htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `[OR]` clause between your conditions to fire your rule for any of the 2 conditions:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.ranglerz.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: not working, showing error that www.ranglerz.com redirected you too many times.

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache? If yes then change `R=301` to `R=308` in above rule and then test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Networking tab what are 301/302/308 redirect URLs you get there.

Comment: same issue with 308

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154325/discussion-between-kashif-latif-and-anubhava).

Comment: It is a bit strange because `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]` is exactly same as `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]` Anyway I have updated code to reflect it now. You may accept the answer if it all worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

The above code will do what you want excellently , just put it in main directory .htaccess file.

Moreover , If you need also to force every site.com to be www.site.come , just replace the flowing  line in the above code :

```
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

with this:

```
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

I have already answered such question before [Apache - how to make http requests into https only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37032053/apache-how-to-make-http-requests-into-https-only/37032433#37032433)